# How can I quickly sort what is peer-reviewed and what isn't in a wide body of literature?

Tags: peer-review, journals, literature-review

I have long list of literature to review that I have inserted in Excel (title, authors, year, journal, etc.). I would like to quickly sort out which journals are peer-reviewed and which aren't.

I know I can check through each individual journal's site to see if they involve peer review, but is there a more efficient tool to do this? A search engine of some kind that would quickly show if a specific journal is reviewed or not?

Comment: The standards of peer review are pretty "volatile", so how would it help. Even for reputable journals you can often not see on the website if there are 1-3 reviewers. Better use https://www.scimagojr.com/ to see if a journal is widely spread, not sure it shows peer review info, even on wikipedia often not listed

Comment: You really would think that with all the talk of "peer-reviewed journals", there would be some kind of straight-forward way to see what journal is or isn't peer-reviewed, but I'm not aware of any way of doing so without manually checking each one. And that doesn't even consider predatory/fraudulent/phony/fake "peer-review", etc. Can't prove it doesn't exist, but I would personally suggest checking with your friendly local librarian to see if they have any suggestions on how you might make the process easier, like a meta-listing that only includes reasonably accepted journals, etc.

Comment: How many unique journal titles are there actually in this list? If it is literature on a single topic this list should probably (hopefully) not be too long...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't actually carried this out, but here's a series of steps that might help:

- The basic idea is that some academic databases have an option to filter search results by peer-reviewed status. You would use such sites.

  - At least two that I know of are EBSCO's Business Source Ultimate (BSU) and ProQuest.
- You start by searching your chosen database with a generic keyword that would feature in every relevant journal (not necessarily every article, but surely every relevant journal) in your database.

  - For example, my field is information systems. So, I search for "information" on Business Source Ultimate (BSU): I get around 2.7 million results.
- Now you filter by peer reviewed jouranls.

  - In BSU, I clicked the Limit To option: "Scholarly (Peer Reviewed) Journals": I get around 580,000 results. I further click "Academic journals" and get 540,000 results.
- You might have to fine-tune the results to get a smaller number.

  - In the case of BSU, I can export a maximum of 25,000 results, so 540,000 is way too much. So, I fine-tuned my search until I found that searching for "information system" gave only 19,000 results.
- Follow the instructions for your database to export ALL the results (not just the 20 or so that appear in your screen) to a spreadsheet file (e.g. Microsoft Excel).

  - EBSCO has instructions for [exporting up to 25,000 results](https://connect.ebsco.com/s/article/Exporting-up-to-25-000-Results?language=en_US). Unfortunately, for some reason, this mass export option is disabled in my school library system, so my step-by-step example has to end here.
- Use the spreadsheet software to remove all the duplicates in the journal column. ([Here are instructions for doing that in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-and-remove-duplicates-00e35bea-b46a-4d5d-b28e-66a552dc138d).)
- So, there's your list of peer-reviewed journals in your field of interest.
- You can compare your original list of journals with your list of peer-reviewed journals.
- If there is any journal from your original list not on the exported list, then do not automatically assume it is not peer-reviewed (my steps are not foolproof); rather you can verify their peer-review status individually just to make sure. But that would be a lot shorter list than what you started with.

  - Actually, you could repeat all the steps above except to include ALL articles without filtering out non-peer-reviewed journals. Then the difference between the two exported journal lists would be a list of non-peer-reviewed journals, if that makes sense.

But all that said, you cannot assume that the database's marking of peer-reviewed journals is absolutely accurate. However, I hope this idea might help.